# Can anyone explain why the limit of this function is nonexistent?

Tags: limits

In the book *1,001 Pre-Calculus Practice Problems For Dummies* (2014 ed.) by Mary Jane Sterling, on Page-122 the following problem is given:

[image]

The solution is given on Page-517, and the answer is: *limit doesn't exist*.

[image]

However, I solved the same problem as follows:

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\tan{x} + 1}{\cos{x}}$$

$$= \lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin{x} + \cos{x}} {1-\sin^2{x}}$$

$$= \frac{\sin{\frac{\pi}{2}} + \cos{\frac{\pi}{2}}}{1- \sin^2{\frac{\pi}{2}}}$$

$$= \frac{1+0}{1-0}$$

$$= 1$$

**What is wrong with my solution?**

Comment: $\sin^2\frac{\pi}{2} $ is $1$, not $0$.

Comment: note that $\tan \frac{\pi}{2} = \pm \infty \neq 0$. Also  $\sin^2 \frac{\pi}{2} = 1 \neq 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your denominator, $\sin \frac {\pi}{2}=1,\neq 0$.